# Can I play the preview at a lower speed?

Tags: editing, preview, kdenlive

**When looking at the the project monitor (red circle in picture), how can I decrease the speed of the playback?**

[image]

I want to check if my transitions and effects are OK, but it is really hard to do this at normal speed. I know I can jump by frame but I would like to keep the speed constant. All I can find on Google is how to slow down clips.